# Docker & Django: Pytest doesn't run

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, pytest

I'm running Docker to load my Django project locally. Pytest works perfectly without Docker, but since I am using Docker, running the command in my container bash brings back lot's of errors.

My docker-compose

```
version: '3'

    services:
      db:
        image: postgres
        ports:
          - "5432:5432"
      web:
        build: .
        env_file: .env
        volumes:
          - .:/code
        ports:
          - "8000:8000"
        depends_on:
          - db
        container_name: local
```

Dockerfile

```
# Pull base image
FROM python:3

# Set environment varibles
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Set work directory
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code

# Install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install pipenv
COPY ./Pipfile /code/Pipfile
RUN pipenv install --deploy --system --skip-lock --dev

# Define ENTRYPOINT
COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

# Copy project
COPY . /code/
```

My initial thought is that docker doesn't let pytest create the test database. Did you ever had issues with that and can tell me how to fix it?

[Console log with failures >](https://pastebin.com/vX5eR16y)

Comment: You have only included a small part of the pytest output. There's 3 errors and 308 failing tests. At least include the tracebacks for all the errors.

Comment: I tried, but SO doesn't allow that much text. So I had to cut it.

Comment: So create a [mcve]. The error seems to be cut in the middle of a word `elf =` should presumably be `self =` You didn't even include the type of exception. It's possible to have pytest just run a few tests at a time. Then you should get a shorter output. For example `test_utils.py` has two `E`, so you can start there.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I now brought it down to one test `tests/checkin/test_views.py` and as it was still too long, I added it to pastebin and inserted the link instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have omitted the most important part of the exceptions, but based on the errors I'm guessing you haven't run your database migrations due to which the Postgres database does not have the necessary tables for the tests.

Comment: Hi Uku Loskit, I changed my post and tested one .py file that fails. I inserted the whole console log here: https://pastebin.com/vX5eR16y

Comment: based on the error, it looks like you are trying to insert an e-mail into an id field. So the error seems to be on the code level rather than related at docker. it would useful to see the definition of `self.user`

Comment: It's really weird. Running it on another computer with pipenv as Dev environment pytest runs smooth.

Answer (score 0):

What container image are you using to run the python code? (it seems to be missing from your compose file).

Based on the deprecation warnings it seems your calling a method that does not exist (i.e. callable is None). Are all dependencies installed in your container?

Additionally, do you have a DockerFile available that installs all dependencies?

Something like:

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.6-slim

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# copy requirements.txt
ADD ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
ADD . /app
```

And then in the compose file you could build it like this:

```
web:
  build:
    context: ./
    dockerfile: /path/to/Dockerfile
  command: cd /app/path/to/where/pytest/should/be/executed && pytest
```

Note that this answer does not rely on a host-mounted volume, but rather copies your code into the container, and creates an image that can be used everywhere.

Comment: Hi benvdh, I added my Dockerfile

Comment: Thanks. It seems ok. You might try something like https://pastebin.com/ to post the full stacktrace and add the link to this question. At the moment it's hard to see the real error in what you've posted.

Comment: Thank you, I have done that, good suggestion: https://pastebin.com/vX5eR16y